# NetworkxとMatplotlibを用いて3次元のグラフを出力したい

Tags: python, python3, matplotlib, networkx

#### 前提

試作として2次元のグラフを出力することができました。ソースコードを記しておきます。
このグラフを3次元で出力してみたいと考え、既存のコードをいじくりまわしていましたが、いろいろ調査してみましたが手詰まりとなってしまいました。
そこで調査不足と指摘されることを覚悟の上でstackoverflowに質問を投稿するに至りました。

#### 実現したいこと

現在、主に実現したいことはこれら3つです。

- 後にリンクを上書きして比較を行いたいため、TkenterのUIはできる限り変更したくない。
- リンクの密集具合に比例してノードの大きさをより大きく見せる。
- テキストファイルのトポロジー情報を読み込んでグラフを出力したい。

#### 該当のソースコード

※冗長になるため、ある程度ソースコードを削っています。そのため、どこかしら不自然な点があるかもしれませんがご了承ください。

- 2次元のグラフを出力するソースコード

```
import networkx as nx
from networkx.algorithms.centrality.betweenness_subset import edge_betweenness_centrality_subset
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter.filedialog as fd

# 入力ウインドウの設定
tki = tk.Tk()  # Tkクラス生成
tki.geometry('350x300')  # 画面サイズ
tki.title('2次元リンク')  # 画面タイトル

# チェックボタンのラベルをリスト化する
chk_txt = ['通常ネットワークの可視化']
chk_bln = {}  #チェックボックスON/OFFの状態

# チェックボタンを動的に作成して配置
for i in range(len(chk_txt)):
    chk_bln[i] = tk.BooleanVar()
    chk = tk.Checkbutton(tki,
                         variable=chk_bln[i],
                         text=chk_txt[i]) 
    chk.place(x=50,
              y=30 + (i * 24))

path = fd.askopenfilename()

# 終了するためのコマンド
def close_window():
    tki.destroy()

# ボタン作成
btn3 = tk.Button(tki,
                 text = '　　　　決定　　　　')
btn3.place(x = 100 , y = 200)

btn4 = tk.Button(tki,
                 text = '終了',
                 command = close_window)
btn4.place(x = 150 , y = 250)

# グラフウインドウの設定
# タイトルで漢字が使えるようフォントを設定
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'Meiryo'

# エッジのリストを読み込む
G = nx.read_edgelist(path,
                     nodetype=int)
edge_size = nx.number_of_edges(G) # リンク数
node_size = nx.number_of_nodes(G) # ノード数

# 図のレイアウト決定 
pos = nx.spring_layout(G, k=0.8)
degs = dict(G.degree)

# 図の作成
plt.figure(figsize=(15, 15))
plt.title("グラフ",
          fontsize = 30,
          fontweight = 'bold')

# ノード
# ノードの大きさを決定
average_deg = sum(d for n,d in G.degree()) / G.number_of_nodes()  #ネットワーク全体の時数の平均値を計算
sizes = [300 * deg * 2 / average_deg for node,deg in G.degree()]  #ノードの次数に比例するようにサイズを設定

# ノード・ラベルの描画
nx.draw_networkx_nodes(G,
                       pos,
                       node_color = 'w',
                       edgecolors = "k",
                       alpha = 0.75,
                       node_size = sizes,
                       linewidths = 2)
nx.draw_networkx_labels(G,
                        pos,
                        font_size = 10)

# トポロジー情報(.txt)の読み込み
with open(path, "r") as tf:
    line = tf.read().split()
ran = int(len(line) / 2)

# グラフの出力
# ボタンクリックイベント(チェック有無をセット)
def btn_click(bln):
    for i in range(len(chk_bln)):
        chk_bln[i].set(bln)

# 各イベントごとの描画方法
def while_1(event):
    if(chk_bln[0].get() == True):
        #通常リンク描画
        nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,
                               pos,
                               edge_color = 'c')
    plt.show()
    
#ボタンに関数をbind
btn3.bind('<Button-1>',while_1)
```

- 3次元のグラフを出力するためにこねくり回したソースコード

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter.filedialog as fd

# 入力ウインドウの設定
#省略

#タイトルで漢字が使えるようフォントを設定
plt.rcParams['font.family'] = 'Meiryo'

# エッジデータを生成
with open(path, "r") as tf:
    line = tf.read().split()
ran = int(len(line) / 2)

# 生成したエッジデータからグラフ作成
G = nx.read_edgelist(path,
                     nodetype=int)
edge_size = nx.number_of_edges(G) # リンク数
node_size = nx.number_of_nodes(G) # ノード数

# spring_layout アルゴリズムで、3次元の座標を生成する
pos = nx.spring_layout(G, k = 0.8, dim = 3)
degs = dict(G.degree)

# 辞書型から配列型に変換
pos_ary = np.array([pos[n] for n in G])

# ここから可視化
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(121, projection="3d")

#グラフタイトルを設定
ax.set_title("3Dでグラフを可視化",size=20)

# 各ノードの位置に点を打つ
ax.scatter(
    pos_ary[:, 0],
    pos_ary[:, 1],
    pos_ary[:, 2],
    s=50,
)

# ノードにラベルを表示する
for n in G.nodes:
    ax.text(*pos[n], n)

# エッジの表示
for e in G.edges:
    node0_pos = pos[e[0]]
    node1_pos = pos[e[1]]
    xx = [node0_pos[0], node1_pos[0]]
    yy = [node0_pos[1], node1_pos[1]]
    zz = [node0_pos[2], node1_pos[2]]
    ax.plot(xx, yy, zz, c="#aaaaaa")

# 8_グラフの出力
# 8.1_ボタンクリックイベント(チェック有無をセット)
def btn_click(bln):
    for i in range(len(chk_bln)):
        chk_bln[i].set(bln)

# 8.2_各イベントごとの描画方法
def while_1(event):
    if(chk_bln[0].get() == True):
        #通常リンク描画
        nx.draw_networkx_edges(G,
                               pos#_ary[:,2],
                               #edge_color = 'c'
                               )
    #出来上がった図を表示
    plt.show()

#ボタンに関数をbind
btn3.bind('<Button-1>',while_1)
```

#### 発生している問題・エラーメッセージ

※個人情報があるため、その部分は伏せさせていただきます。

```
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:/Program Files/Python36/3D_test2.py", line 106, in while_1
    ,edge_color = 'c'
  File "C:\Users\████\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_pylab.py", line 684, in draw_networkx_edges
    alpha=alpha,
  File "C:\Users\████\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py", line 1393, in __init__
    self.set_segments(segments)
  File "C:\Users\████\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py", line 1408, in set_segments
    self._paths = [mpath.Path(_seg) for _seg in _segments]
  File "C:\Users\████\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\collections.py", line 1408, in <listcomp>
    self._paths = [mpath.Path(_seg) for _seg in _segments]
  File "C:\Users\████\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\path.py", line 132, in __init__
    cbook._check_shape((None, 2), vertices=vertices)
  File "C:\Users\████\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\matplotlib\cbook\__init__.py", line 2304, in _check_shape
    f"{k!r} must be {len(target_shape)}D "
ValueError: 'vertices' must be 2D with shape (M, 2). Your input has shape (2, 3).
```

- トポロジー情報

```
1 10
1 11
1 14
1 20
2 9
2 12
2 13
2 15
2 16
3 10
3 11
3 20
4 5
4 8
4 9
5 4
5 9
6 7
6 14
7 6
7 18
8 4
8 11
8 14
8 19
9 2
9 4
9 5
10 1
10 3
11 1
11 3
11 8
11 13
12 2
12 16
13 2
13 11
14 1
14 6
14 8
15 2
15 17
15 21
16 2
16 12
17 15
18 7
18 21
19 8
19 20
20 1
20 3
20 19
20 21
21 15
21 18
21 20
```

#### 試したこと

チェックボックスに何も入力しなければ出力は行われます。
[image: ノード数は20個]
106行目の「edge_color = 'c'」をコメントアウトしていますが、これは上記と同様のエラーが発生したためです。
「pos_ary[n]」と表記した場合は以下のようなエラー文が出力されました。

```
>>> Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\3D_test2.py", line 105, in while_1
    pos_ary[n]
IndexError: index 21 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 21
```

105行目において「pos[n]」と表記したところ、これまた別のエラー文が出ました。これは「pos_ary[n-1]」と表記したものと同様です。

```
>>> Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1705, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Program Files\Python36\3D_test2.py", line 105, in while_1
    pos[n]#_ary[:,2],
  File "C:\Users\████\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_pylab.py", line 656, in draw_networkx_edges
    edge_pos = np.asarray([(pos[e[0]], pos[e[1]]) for e in edgelist])
  File "C:\Users\████\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python36\site-packages\networkx\drawing\nx_pylab.py", line 656, in <listcomp>
    edge_pos = np.asarray([(pos[e[0]], pos[e[1]]) for e in edgelist])
IndexError: index 10 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 3
```

#### 補足情報

python 3.6.8
networkx 2.5.1
matplotlib 3.3.4

Comment: 提示されたソースコードはどちらも内容を削りすぎて完結しておらず、問題を再現出来なくなっているようです。(ただし版数(Python3.11.0で各モジュールも最新)の違いかもしれませんが) それぞれ単独で実行できて問題を再現できる程度に手直ししてみてください。

Comment: 試しにpython3.6.8で試してみたところ、成功しました。私は『Python1年生　体験してわかる！　会話でまなべる！　プログラミングのしくみ(著:森巧尚)』という書籍からPythonを学びました。当初Pythonバージョン3.11を用いて学習していましたが、ライブラリの導入が出来ず、[『Python１年生』NumPyが取り込めない時の対処方法について](https://www.chuta-kun.com/basic-for-python/)というサイトを参考にしてバージョンを落とした経緯があります。そのため、kunif氏のもう一つの推測の通り、各モジュールのバージョンによるエラーが発生していると考えられます。

Comment: 3Dで可視化する方のソースコードの誤字を修正しました。もしかしたらこれが原因で再現ができなかった可能性があります。

Comment: ちなみにチェックボックスをチェックした時に、何のために何のデータをどのように表示したいのでしょうか？(例えばコメントに書かれた「各イベントごとの描画方法」とはどんなことでしょう？) それは実現したいことの3項目のうち、どれに関わってくるのでしょうか？ もしかしたらこんな記事が何か参考になるかもしれません。[NetworkXで作成したグラフを3次元にプロットする](https://analytics-note.xyz/graph-theory/networkx-matplotlib-3d-plot/), [\[Python\]NetworkXでQiitaのタグ関係図を描く](https://qiita.com/inoory/items/088f719f2fd9a2ea4ee5)

Comment: 自身の英語サイトでの質問に回答が付いたようですね。[I want to output a 3D graph using Networkx and Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/q/74368905/9014308)

Comment: そのようです。解決済みにしておきます。

Answer (score 1):

自身が質問していたstackoverflowの英語サイトに回答が付きましたので、共有させていただきます。[I want to output a 3D graph using Networkx and Matplotlib](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74368905/i-want-to-output-a-3d-graph-using-networkx-and-matplotlib?noredirect=1#comment131296593_74368905)

## ソースコード

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from mpl_toolkits.mplot3d import Axes3D
import networkx as nx
import numpy as np
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import messagebox
import tkinter.filedialog as fd

# Input Window Settings
tki = tk.Tk()  # Tk class generation
tki.geometry('350x300')  # screen size
tki.title('link')  # screen title
# List check button labels
chk_txt = ['Normal network visualization']
chk_bln = {}  #Check box ON/OFF status

# Dynamically create and place check buttons
for i in range(len(chk_txt)):
    chk_bln[i] = tk.BooleanVar()
    chk = tk.Checkbutton(tki,variable=chk_bln[i],text=chk_txt[i]) 
    chk.place(x=50,y=30 + (i * 24))
    
path = fd.askopenfilename()
# Command to exit
def close_window():
    tki.destroy()

# button generation
btn3 = tk.Button(tki,text = '  decision  ')
btn3.place(x = 100 , y = 200)
btn4 = tk.Button(tki,text = 'exit',command = close_window)
btn4.place(x = 150 , y = 250)

# Graph Window Settings
# Generate edge data
with open(path, "r") as tf:
    line = tf.read().split()
ran = int(len(line) / 2)

# Create graphs from generated edge data
G = nx.read_edgelist(path,nodetype=int)
edge_size = nx.number_of_edges(G) # number of edges
node_size = nx.number_of_nodes(G) # number of nodes

# spring_layout algorithm to generate 3D coordinates
pos = nx.spring_layout(G, k = 0.8, dim = 3)
degs = dict(G.degree)
average_deg = sum(d for n,d in G.degree()) / G.number_of_nodes()  #Calculate the average number of hours for the entire network
sizes = [100 * deg * 2 / average_deg for node,deg in G.degree()]  #Sized to be proportional to node order
# Conversion from dictionary type to array type
pos_ary = np.array([pos[n] for n in G])

# visualization
fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(121, projection="3d")

#Set graph title
ax.set_title("3D graph",size=20)

# Dot the position of each node
[ax.scatter(pos_ary[i, 0],pos_ary[i, 1],pos_ary[i, 2],s=sizes[i],color='b',alpha=0.5) for i in range(len(pos_ary))]

# Display labels on nodes
for n in G.nodes:
    ax.text(*pos[n], n)

# Graph Output
# Button click event (set to checked or unchecked)
def btn_click(bln):
    for i in range(len(chk_bln)):
        chk_bln[i].set(bln)

# How to draw for each event
def while_1(event):
    if(chk_bln[0].get() == True):
        for e in G.edges:
            node0_pos = pos[e[0]]
            node1_pos = pos[e[1]]
            xx = [node0_pos[0], node1_pos[0]]
            yy = [node0_pos[1], node1_pos[1]]
            zz = [node0_pos[2], node1_pos[2]]
            ax.plot(xx, yy, zz, c="k",lw=2)
    #View the resulting diagram
    plt.show()

#Bind function to button
btn3.bind('<Button-1>',while_1)
tk.mainloop()
```

## 出力結果

- チェックボックスにチェックを入れない場合
  [image: リンクなし]
- チェックボックスにチェックを入れた場合
  [image: リンクあり]